# OMPL: How could I use OMPL with Cartesian Coordenates

Tags: ros, ompl, ompl-ros-interface, arm-navigation

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi everyone!!!!

I need work with OMPL, but in a special way, The Input is a set of cartesian coordinates and I need the output in cartesian coordinates.

Can anyone help me?

PD: The tutorial of ompl in the wiki runs in diamondback but it is not
working in electric

Thanks!

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/30675/ompl:-how-could-i-use-ompl-with-cartesian-coordenates/) by [Ivan Rojas Jofre](https://answers.ros.org/users/398/ivan-rojas-jofre/) on ROS Answers with karma: 70 on 2012-03-28

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hello Ivan,

What robot are you using this for? Do you have a collision checker?
It seems to me what you can do is just use OMPL directly. Define a SE3StateSpace (which represents a position in space + orientation) or RealVectorStateSpace(3) (to represent just a 3D point), set the bounds for the space and plan there directly. You do need to specify your collision checker directly however. Check http://ompl.info for tutorials on how to do this, or post questions here again.

Ioan

---

Originally posted by [isucan](https://answers.ros.org/users/1805/isucan/) with karma: 1055 on 2012-03-28

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Ivan Rojas Jofre](https://answers.ros.org/users/398/ivan-rojas-jofre/) on 2012-04-03**:
Thanks for your answer,

Answer (score 0):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Ivan,

Are you using OMPL directly? The start trees cannot be initialized by a planner when there are no valid starting states. Is your start state in collision? Or at a state that does not satisfy the state validity constraints?
If you are using ROS, make sure you turn on DEBUG and see if you get more information.

Ioan

---

Originally posted by [isucan](https://answers.ros.org/users/1805/isucan/) with karma: 1055 on 2012-04-03

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1